# using structs as parameter

Tags: c#, .net

I need to define an `enum` with decimal values, but since that this is not possible I have read a solution as to use `struct` instead, so I have the following:

```
        public struct r_type
        {
            public const double c001_a1 = 0.1;
            public const double c001_a2 = 0.2;
            public const double c001_a4 = 0.4;
            public const double c001_a8 = 0.8;
        }
```

and I'm trying to call this as parameter in a function, like the following:

```
public static void SetRValue(string product_id, r_type r)
```

however when calling this in my code it gives an error:

```
SetRValue(product.id, r_type.c001_a1);
```

the error is:

> Error 5 Argument 2: 
>   cannot convert from 'double' to 'myproject.class1.r_type'

**edit**: I need that my `r` parameter can accept only a given range of values, not any `double` value. It is the same thing that I would do if I could have an `enum` that can accept decimal values as stated in my `struct` above.

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what is happening. Are you passing a double or are you passing the struct? Your signature must match what you are passing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method expect a struct value, instead you give it a const double value.

Change your method signature:

```
public static void SetRValue(string product_id, double r)
```

In this case you can use a `static class` which are perfect for defining const values:

```
public static class r_type
{
    public const double c001_a1 = 0.1;
    public const double c001_a2 = 0.2;
    public const double c001_a4 = 0.4;
    public const double c001_a8 = 0.8;
}
```

You can also narrow it to this few options, however I doubt it is worth an effort:

```
public class r_type { 

    // make it private not to create more than you want
    private r_type(double value) {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public double Value { get; private set;}

    public static implicit operator double(r_type r)
    {
        return r.Value;
    }

    // your enum values below
    public static readonly r_type A1 = new r_type(0.1);
    public static readonly r_type A2 = new r_type(0.2);
    public static readonly r_type A4 = new r_type(0.2);
    public static readonly r_type A8 = new r_type(0.8);
}
```

And your method:

```
public static void SetRValue(string product_id, r_type r)
{
    // you can use it explicitely
    var t = r.Value;
    // or sometimes even better, implicitely
    // thanks to implicit conversion operator
    double g = r;
}
```

**BTW:** Consider using a well established C# convention to call your classes like `MyClass` instead of `my_class` or `myClass`. Check [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: if I chance the signature `SetRValue` can accept any value of `r` while I want to narrow the possibilities in the given `consts` values defined, much like I would do with an `enum` structure.

Comment: Check also a cool possibility of using an implicit conversion operator. Included in edit.

Comment: that's cool, of course I'm iterating more than 4 values and will help to prevent wrong values passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a double into a method that is expecting a struct.  Either change the function signature to take a double or pass in the struct.
SetRValue(product.id, r_type);
It really depends on what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I need to pass one value of the structure, so not any `double` but a value that is part of the structure / class as I would do with an `enum` type

Answer (score 0):

To simulate an `enum` you can do this:

```
public sealed class r_type
{
    private double Value;

    public static readonly r_type c001_a1 = new r_type(0.1);
    public static readonly r_type c001_a2 = new r_type(0.2);
    public static readonly r_type c001_a4 = new r_type(0.4);
    public static readonly r_type c001_a8 = new r_type(0.8);

    private r_type(double d)
    {
        Value = d;
    }

    public static implicit operator double(r_type d)
    {
        return d.Value;
    }
}
```

Then you can call the method as you do.